# Save input data to database from web application

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web-applications

Hy,
My registration page does not save input data to database.
Here is my html code

```
@page
@model PWAPI.Model.RegistrationModel.Registration
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "User Registration";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Registration</h3>
    <form method="post" asp-page="RegistrationPage/Registration"></form>
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Username" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Email" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Password" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Confrim Password</td>
            <td>
                <input asp-for="@Model.ConfirmPassword" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
                <br />
                <a href="/LoginPage/Login">Login</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

It looks like this
 [My Registration page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLRLn.png)

My Registration model

```
[Table("Registration")]
public class Registration
{
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name ="Confirm Password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password and Confrim Password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Things I'm trying to do after and I think this is where I'm doing something wrong.

```
public class RegistrationModel : PageModel
{
    private Registration registration { get; set; }
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            registration = new Registration();
            string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PWAPI"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_get_registration", con)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", registration.Email);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", registration.Password);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConfirmPassword", registration.ConfirmPassword);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return RedirectToPage("/LoginPage/Login");
        }
        else
        {
            return new RedirectToPageResult("/RegistrationPage/Registration");
        }
    }
}
```

When I click 'save', Nothing happens. The page won't even refresh and no inputs are saved to my database.
furthermore, when I click save without anything written on it, there is no exception error.
EDIT: my stored procedure
EDIT 2: My database has userid as well but It's auto incremental.

```
CREATE Procedure sp_get_registration
@Email varchar(50),
@Password nvarchar(50),
@ConfirmPassword nvarchar(50)
as
Insert into Registration(Email, Password, ConfirmPassword)
Values (@Email, @Password, @ConfirmPassword)
```

Comment: Are you able to debug your C# code?

Comment: You are opening and closing the form on the same line. `asp-page="RegistrationPage/Registration"></form>`. You should move `</form>` after `</table>`

Comment: Hy @Chetan,
it now refreshes after save but it still won't record the data in my database. Unfortunately, I don't know how to debug in web application.  I've plced the break point in Iactionresult and after clicking save, debug won't start.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/form-basics

Comment: Hy @Chetan, That link was helpful but it doesn't contain how to add data from .html.cs instead all work is done from html page.